# MFMailComposeViewController crash on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am using the below code for both iPhone & iPad.

```
if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
{
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

         MFMailComposeViewController *mailcomposer=[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
         [mailcomposer setMailComposeDelegate:self];
         [mailcomposer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:recipients]];
         [self presentViewController:mailcomposer animated:YES completion:nil];
      });
}
```

It's work fine in iPhone but in case of iPad the modal has open and after few seconds it's automatically got dismissed. After putting it into debug mode I found below log.

```
viewServiceDidTerminateWithError: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain error 3.)" UserInfo=0x7fbb904040f0 {Message=Service Connection Interrupted}
<MFMailComposeRemoteViewController: 0x7fbb928b3250> timed out waiting for fence barrier from com.apple.MailCompositionService
```

Comment: iPad or iPad Simulator? You can't use it on Simulator.

Comment: iPad simulator..... ooo...

Comment: The MailCompose Controlelr only works on physical devices/iPads

Comment: why the " dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{"?

Comment: @MattiaLancieri because this method get called from a secondary thread body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the `MFMailComposeViewController` on a real physical Device/iPad, but it might give issues on the simulator.

Comment: This is not true, it should work on the simulator as well. I've build many app where I have use the `MFMailComposeViewController` in the simulator before testing it on a real device.

Comment: @rokoenes I am not sure how it's work with you. But I tried it in real device it's work fine while it's crashed on simulator.

Comment: @rckoenes so? Why is it working then on his real ipad? I can't believe that you downvote the solution to this problem...

Comment: @TapasPal can you please mark this as solution to your problem?

Comment: @DanielBocksteger because you're stating that you **have** to run the `MFMailComposeViewController ` on a real device. Which is not true.

Comment: I could search for the dev-forum post again, but an developer (iOS) there said exactly what i'm stating.